# Visibility of an ASP.Net button which depends if a file exists in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visibility

I have a gridview which has a few rows (each with a unique `rowId`), and each line has a `FileUpload` control, now everything works okay with `FileUpload`.

(my uploaded file database image can be seen below)

I have the download button, which also works okay, however I want to make this button invisible if no file exists for the corresponding row.

Nothing proper comes to my mind.

My button and `FileUpload` control:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BatchList">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibt_Download" runat="server" src="Images/Download.png" CommandName="Download" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ></asp:ImageButton>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UploadBatchList">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Header" ToolTip="Upload Batch List" runat="server" Text="UBL"></asp:Label>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fu_UploadBatchList" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="btn_Upload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btn_Upload_Click" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

This is how it looks on my gridView

[image]

When gridview is first created the green dots must not be visible if a file has been uploaded before.

My file database:

[image]

Comment: It more or less comes down to this: When you upload a file, you make a change in regards to that specific record. See if this change exists for the record and if not make the button invisible. If you provide some sample code, I'll try to help you with an answer. :)

Comment: @Bazzz I included some code and images. When my table is first created, the buttons must be created invisible if no file exists.

Comment: I'm under the impression that the table that you are showing is not the one that the GridView is databound with (I see a comment field that has no field in the table?). Please also show the table that you are databinding with the GridView and please add the code that handles the file upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can check some property of the data item (DocName in your case) if it contains a value (it might not work when copy-pasted, I'm a little bit improvising):

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_Upload" runat="server" 
            Text="Upload" 
            Visible='<% DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocName") == null %>
            OnClick="btn_Upload_Click" />
```

Or you can create a function that will evaluate the visibility. See [Mastering ASP.NET DataBinding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8659/Mastering-ASP-NET-DataBinding) for more.

Comment: it's not that button, besides I'm not sure that the `Container.DataItem` has a property named "DocName", this field seems to be in another database table. Waiting for HOY to provide more info.